# Turn an array of objects into a map array with a property of type array using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, reduce

I need to display a company list with all users related (followers) to each company:
This is the current array data structure:

```
[
  {
    company:"CompanyName1",
    type:"Type1",
    info: {}
    userId: "U001"
  },
  {
    company:"CompanyName1",
    type:"Type1",
    info: {}
    userId: "U002"
  },
  {
    company:"CompanyName1",
    type:"Type1",
    info: {}
    userId: "U003"
  },
  {
    company:"CompanyName2",
    type:"Type2",
    info: {}
    userId: "U001"
  }
]
```

And I need the data structure in this format using pure javascript (map, reduce, etc)

```
[
  {
    company:"CompanyName1",
    type:"Type1",
    info:{},
    userIds: ["U001", "U002", "U003"]
  },
  {
   company:"CompanyName2",
   type:"Type2",
   info:{},
   userIds: ["U001"]
  }
]
```

Comment: What issues are you having when you try to do this?

Comment: Note that expected results are invalid array structure

Comment: I doubt your server is giving you JSON that includes `"info": {Object}`. Can you clarify what's going on there?

Comment: this looks like you need a change to the endpoint that you are calling to get this data

Comment: @Andy its just an example to avoid expanding the Object structure, you can just forget about this property, Thanks

Comment: mapping yes, but that aggregation of the `userId` to `usersId` seems to me that needs to be done server side and perhaps especially for large data. just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table for grouping same companies.

```js
var array = [{ company: "CompanyName1", type: "Type1", info: {}, userId: "U001" }, { company: "CompanyName1", type: "Type1", info: {}, userId: "U002" }, { company: "CompanyName1", type: "Type1", info: {}, userId: "U003" }, { company: "CompanyName2", type: "Type2", info: {}, userId: "U001" }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!hash[o.company]) {
        hash[o.company] = { company: o.company, type: o.type, info: o.info, userIds: [] }
        result.push(hash[o.company]);
    }
    hash[o.company].userIds.push(o.userId);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I just realized that your response is returning an object, not an array, every company that had been added as property into the result object it should have been added as an item into the final array

Comment: please edit your question and add a **valid** result of grouping. actually, you have an array with properties, which does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, your results are stored in the `companyList` array - let me know if you need any clarification of what's going on here. Basically it's just a simple [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
 let origionalData = [{
        "company": "CompanyName1",
        "type": "Type1",
        "info": "",
        "userId": "U001"
    },
    {
        "company": "CompanyName1",
        "type": "Type1",
        "info": "",
        "userId": "U002"
    },
    {
        "company": "CompanyName1",
        "type": "Type1",
        "info": "",
        "userId": "U003"
    },
    {
        "company": "CompanyName2",
        "type": "Type2",
        "info": "",
        "userId": "U001"
    }
];
```

Then:

```
let companyList = []

origionalData.forEach((data, index) => {

    if (companyList[data.company]) {
        companyList[data.company].userIds.push(data.userId)
    } else {
        companyList[data.company] = {
            "type": data.type,
            "info": "",
            "userIds": [data.userIds]
        }
    }
})

console.log(companyList); // Here are the results!
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some assumptions about the data you need as a result. I was unsure if you wanted to use the company field in each object as given, or increment it, so I used it as given. I also returned a valid object, because you asked for an invalid result. Anyway, is this what you were going for?

```
const original = [
  {
    "company":"CompanyName1",
    "type":"Type1",
    "info": {},
    "userId": "U001"
  },
  {
    "company":"CompanyName1",
    "type":"Type1",
    "info": {},
    "userId": "U002"
  },
  {
    "company":"CompanyName1",
    "type":"Type1",
    "info": {},
    "userId": "U003"
  },
  {
    "company":"CompanyName2",
    "type":"Type2",
    "info": {},
    "userId": "U001"
  }
];

const result = original.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push({
    [item.company]: {
      type: item.type,
      info: item.info,
      userId: item.userId
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: This is a partial solution, your solution is missing the userIds (array) aggregation.